# How to get antlr to parse a beancount comment?

Tags: antlr4, beancount

I've been trying to write a parser for the [Beancount format](https://beancount.github.io/docs/beancount_language_syntax.html) with Antlr4. I can't seem to parse comments properly.

Smallest grammar to reproduce the problem -

```
grammar Beancount;

trStatement: tr_header NEWLINE (tr_comment NEWLINE)*;
tr_header: date quoted_string;

date: DATE;
quoted_string: STR;

tr_comment: ';' (~NEWLINE)*;

fragment DIGIT: [0-9];
fragment YEAR: DIGIT DIGIT DIGIT DIGIT;
fragment MONTH: DIGIT DIGIT;
fragment DAY: DIGIT DIGIT;
DATE: YEAR [-] MONTH [-] DAY;


fragment WORD: [\p{Alnum}\-_]+;
ACCOUNT: WORD (':' WORD)+;

WHITESPACE: (' ' | '\t')+ -> skip;
NEWLINE: ('\r' '\n'?) | '\n';

STR: '"' (~[\\"] | '\\' [\\"()])* '"';
```

Text I'm trying to parse -

```
2019-04-14 "Cat Powder"
  ; Help
  ; Hello
```

When trying to parse the `trStatement` rule, I get the following errors -

```
2:4 token recognition error at: 'Help\n'
3:4 token recognition error at: 'Hello\n'
```

I've been trying this in Dart, but I get the same error in the [Antlr Web Editor](http://lab.antlr.org/) as well. (Remember to clear the Lexer tab, if you're trying it out)

[image]

If I remove the following lexer lines -

```
fragment WORD: [\p{Alnum}\-_]+;
ACCOUNT: WORD (':' WORD)+;
```

then the error changes to -

```
2:4 token recognition error at: 'H'
2:5 token recognition error at: 'e'
2:6 token recognition error at: 'l'
2:7 token recognition error at: 'p'
3:4 token recognition error at: 'H'
3:5 token recognition error at: 'e'
3:6 token recognition error at: 'l'
3:7 token recognition error at: 'l'
3:8 token recognition error at: 'o'
```

This makes me believe that even though these lexical terms aren't being used in the example. They are intefering in someway.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: I think your problem lies with the fact that tr_comment is not a lever token. The character sequences 'help' and 'hello' are likely being tokenised as WORDS, so they will never match in your tr_comment parser rule. One thing you can try is to convert tr_comment to TR_COMMENT (making it a lever rule), and make sure that it is above the WORD rule.

Answer (score 0):

The input `Help` and `Hello` cannot be handled by any of your lexer rules, which is what the error means. If you change the rule:

```
ACCOUNT: WORD (':' WORD)+;
```

into:

```
ACCOUNT: WORD (':' WORD)*;
```

then it'd probably work (not tested). That way, both `Help` and `Hello` will become `ACCOUNT` tokens.

But, as already mentioned in the comments, a comment is (usually) better suited as a lexer rule:

```
COMMENT : ';' ~[\r\n]*;
```

And in a lot of grammars, comments are often discarded from the token stream:

```
COMMENT : ';' ~[\r\n]* -> skip;
```

in which case you don't need to litter your parser grammar with all the positions a `COMMENT` could occur.

Note that there is a Yacc/Bison grammar in the Beancount repository which you might have a look at for inspiration: https://github.com/beancount/beancount/blob/master/beancount/parser/grammar.y